# removing stopwords after word tokenizing and lower casing

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to NLP and facing some challenges in performing the following task.
I want to perform these order of tasks.
1.Sentenence Tokenize
2.Word tokenize on each sentence
3.Lower case
4.Stop word removal
5.Lemmatizing each word

I tried to write a function do the above task

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import random
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def text_processing(input_str):
    tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(input_str)#sentence tokenizing
    for words in tokens:
        each_word = nltk.word_tokenize(words)#word tokeninzing
        for i in each_word:
            lower_words = i.lower()
            stopwords_removed = [w for w in lower_words if not w in stopwords]
            print(stopwords_removed)
```

when i call the above function

```
text_processing(new_doc)
```

I am getting this error : TypeError: argument of type 'LazyCorpusLoader' is not iterable. How to overcome this error.

Comment: Please avoid the idiom you're using in your code, it iterates through the same sentence several times, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126442/combining-text-stemming-and-removal-of-punctuation-in-nltk-and-scikit-learn/26132560#26132560

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use stopwords directly. 
Instead, you should download the resources first by typing this in your Jupyter or terminal:

```
nltk.download()
```

And than a downloader will show up, choose Corpus -> stopwords, and download.
[image]

And then you can use stopwords by this:

```
my_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Reference: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/
[NLTK and Stopwords Fail #lookuperror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693736/nltk-and-stopwords-fail-lookuperror)